# Android xml avoid overlap constraintLayout border radius by child constraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have some issue with follow structure:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_rectangle_radius10">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    /// many views here

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    /// many views here

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/third"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/second"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    /// many views here

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Programatically it can be 3 inner constraints or 4 or 2.

Root Constraint has round border radius.
Programatically when one of inner items clicked I set to this item background color, BUT when its first or last it overlap root border radius.

Note:

1. No need to suggest cardview as root element (not my option)
2. "Smart play" with margins/paddings also doesn't suit me because it should be changed programatically.

Is there some option to do it via XML?

When I added background color to first element it's top start/end corners not rounded.[image]

Comment: can you show what it should look like and how it looks like now?

Comment: Added result image with problem explanation.

Comment: are you saying that the gray one should have rounded corders ?

Comment: Abhinav, yes this is what i want

Comment: may i ask why are you using nested layout? while you know it is not good for performance

Comment: I need nested, each child has complicated ui inside + should be clickable + can have different background color + can have ripple effect + can be visible/gone with all child views.

Answer (score 0):

- First it is not recommended to nest layouts if you are going to use constraintLayout.
- Second is how to design your view smoothly?
  one of constraintlayout benefits is using the drag and drop option, therefore, start by doing that and ensure to place every item in its right place (but do not apply any constraint yet).
  once all items are on the layout, click any item and look at the tool bar above the mobile screen, there is a magic wound, click on it, the constraint will be generated automatically based on the way you orgnized the view on the screen.

  once that is done, now you might need to adjust the margins a bit according to the requirements.

also please assign id to each view before clicking the magic wound.

I hope I was helpful.